# Can't connect to devices behind TP Link and otherwise

Tags: networking, wireless-router, home-networking, wireless-access-point

I bought a TP Link N Router to use it as access point.

My PC(10.0.0.10/24) is directly connected to my modem (10.0.0.138/24). The TP-Link(10.0.0.50/24) is also connected to the router. My Laptop (10.0.0.100/24 (DHCP from TPLink)) is connected over WLAN with my TP-Link.

My PC and My Laptop have both Internet. But they can't access each other. When I connect my laptop with lan directly to my modem it works. But over wlan or lan over the TP Link they cant connect to each other.

The PC is also not allowed to connect to the TP Link.

All devices in the WLan can access each other.

I tried to disable securities firewalls all on the TP Link still no connections.

[Network Graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5APh.png)

Comment: Likely the TP Link is doing routing, NAT, and DHCP. You need to disable all that and put it in bridge mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your picture, you need to plug the modem into a LAN port on the TPLink device rather then a WAN port.  You should also get rid of the network 10.0.0.50/24 - you really should not have the LAN and WAN on the same subnet.

The way I would do things are as follows (if setting up from scratch):

1. Connect the modem and notebook to LAN ports on the TPLink device.
2. Configure a static IP address on the tplink LAN port and disable the
   WAN port.  (I'd use 10.0.0.253 in this case, but thats just me).
3. Ensure the TPLink device is not acting as a DHCP server.
4. Plug the modem into the TPLink device on a LAN port.
5. (I would configure the modem to use 10.0.0.254, and have a DHCP range of
   10.0.0.100-10.0.0.200, again thats just me)
6. If you have more then 4 devices which need to be connected to the lan
   with wires, purchase a switch, move everything on the LAN ports of the
   TPLink router to the switch, and cable a LAN port from the router to the
   switch (you can leave some on lan ports on router, some on switch, but you
   will probably get better performance with all of them on the switch because
   the router is most likely creating a virtual switch and doing processing
   on each packet)

Comment: 1. done  
2. done  
3. not sure how i get my dhcp work on my speedtouch 546. (no dhcp settings in the webinterface)  
4. done  
5. 3.  
6. only have 4 devices on the modem over lan (printer, pc1, pc2, tp-link) TP Link have only wlan devices (modem excluded).  
  
Get now also the device name of the TP-Link its a MR3420v2

Comment: See http://screenshots.portforward.com/routers/Thomson/SpeedTouch_546v5/DHCP_DHCP_Server_Server_Config.htm and http://www.speedguide.net/images/hardware/technicolorthomson/st546_ug.pdf

Comment: ok i see. but i dont get it run my pc dont get an ip from the speedtouch. here my config: http://imgur.com/FCpI9DC. the pc is directly connected to the modem and he dont get an ip. speedtouch 546_v6 (Firmware 7.4.4.6).

Comment: Sorry, I really can't understand what you are saying.  (If the PC is the only device not working, plug it into a LAN port on the router)

Comment: no any device dont get an ip from the configured dhcp. it seems to be broken in the shared internet configuration.

Comment: but it should not make so much different when the TP Link is dhcp server or?

Comment: If the tplink is used as the DHCP server (im guesssing) it will set itself as the gateway which is wrong. ( dont have one and I know a dhcp server can sometimes be programmed to provide a default gateway other then the router - you need to make sure the default gateway points to the modem.  Also,  you dont want t run 2 dhcp servers on the same network as unless carefully configured they will break things.

Comment: thankyou for your time. did now install openwrt on my tplink. configured it the same way and now it all works.