# Can't connect to other devices on same network - TP Link Archer C6 in Access Point mode with Fritzbox 7530

Tags: networking, home-networking, fritzbox

I have an issue where only some of my devices are able to connect to each other. It looks to me like a NAT issue, where only devices connected to the same router can see each other, but all devices are on the same subnet, and not all devices on the same router can see each other.

Here's a diagram of the setup (sorry for my poor diagramming skills): [network diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJfUg.png)

The Fritzbox is connected to the Internet via a fibre modem, which is plugged into LAN port 1 on the Fritzbox.

The PC and Laptop are connected to a Netgear GS105 unmanaged switch, and from that to the Fritzbox on LAN port 2.

There's another computer connected via cable to LAN port 3.

The TP-Link Archer C6 is connected to the Fritzbox in Fritzbox's LAN port 4 and one of the Archer C6's LAN ports, and there are both wired and wireless devices connected to the Archer C6. The Archer C6 is set up in Access Point mode and its DHCP server is turned off.

All devices have Internet access.

The PC and the laptop can see each other (pings work, and I can access a web server running on the PC from the laptop).

The devices connected to the Archer C6 can see each other and the Fritzbox (pings work, they show up on a uPnP scan).

All devices have a 192.168.178.xxx IP address and 192.168.178.1 as the gateway (this is the IP address of the Fritzbox).

BUT:

- I cannot ping or connect to the PC's web server from any device connected to the Archer C6.
- I cannot ping or connect to any device connected to the Archer C6 from the PC or laptop.
- I also cannot ping or connect to the laptop connected to LAN 3 from the PC, laptop, or a wireless device connected to the Archer C6.
- I also cannot ping or connect to the PC or laptop on LAN 2 or the laptop on LAN 3 from a wireless device connected to the Fritzbox's WLAN (normally disabled, I turned it on for testing purposes only).

So to me it looks like the Fritzbox is preventing network connections between devices, but not all network connections (since the connection between PC and laptop works). I'm at a loss for what to test next!

I would be really grateful for any pointers - I've done a tonne of googling and haven't found any useful information. [This person](https://superuser.com/questions/1015991/cant-connect-to-devices-behind-tp-link-and-otherwise) seems to have had a similar issue, but they seem to have resolved it by installing OpenWRT, so I don't think that question should be marked resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been a problem caused by the automatic configuration sent by my ISP (DNS:Net). I can't prove it, but it looks like LAN devices were in guest mode and not allowed to speak to one another. Setting up the connection manually resolved the issue. Steps in the fritzbox admin:

- Click 'Internet'
- Click 'Zugangsdaten'
- Choose 'weiterer Internetanbieter' from the list
- Enter a friendly name
- Choose 'Anschluss an externes Modem oder Router'
- Choose 'Internetverbindung selbst aufbauen'
- Choose 'Ja' to 'Werden Zugangsdaten benötigt?'
- Enter the username and password supplied by the ISP
- Enter 1000 MBit/s for both Downstream and Upstream
- Expand 'Verbindungseinstellung ändern'
- Check 'VLAN für den Internetzugang verwenden'
- Enter 37 for the VLAN-ID. Why 37? No idea. I got it from [here](https://www.router-forum.de/avm-fritzbox/fritzbox-7530-netzwerkgeraete-nicht-aufrufbar-und-kein-internetzugang-ueber-lan-neu.t71349/#post-321136).
- Make sure 'Internetzugang nach dem "Übernehmen" prüfen' is checked
- 'Übernehmen' and hope for the best!

Answer (score 0):

I got here while setting up my plex media server on a Fritzbox7530 hosted network (also on dns-net). Above solution helped me open up communication between the devices in the LAN.

But, I was having an issue with not being able to access the Plex server through the LAN despite the VLAN setup mentioned above.

Additional step to enable LAN access for devices inside the LAN :

- Go to Home Network > Network >  network Settings
- Scroll down to DNS Rebind Protection
- Add "plex.media"
- Apply and reboot